# Primer proyecto en Gradle - faltan carpetas

Tags: java, gradle

Estoy tratando de crear el primer proyecto en Gradle pero al iniciarlo no me salen todas las carpetas que deberían.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mirando alguna entrada en Stackoverflow he encontrado que puede ser problema de la configuración:

*File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> check the "Create directories for empty content roots automatically".*

Mi problema es que tampoco puedo marcar esta opción:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien me puede decir qué está pasando?

Como se ve en la imagen 1, aparece ya un error, que mediante la pestaña 'Problems' no puedo ver de qué fallo/problema se trata.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

saludos.

Comment: Al pie de ambas imágenes aparece un error indicando que el directorio java home proporcionado no es correcto. ¿Has comprobado si ese directorio existe y si tienes un jdk 17 instalado ahí?

Comment: @RubioRic, lo tenía pero instalé JDK15 porque me daba error a la hora de usar el Gradle, y porque me estaban recomendando haber instalado el 15. No sé si reinstalar completamente IntelliJ y evitar así problemas, qué opinas?

Comment: Yo soy más de Eclipse. Si estás usando Windows, verifica las variables de entorno y mira qué pone la de JAVA_HOME. Editala si es necesario para que apunte al JDK que quieres y reinicia IntelliJ

Comment: @RubioRic, finalmente he reinstalado y ha funcionado ya todo bien. Muchas gracias por el comentario porque así he conseguido avanzar y decidirme por la reinstalación